# IntelliJ IDEA new message regarding Spring contexts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am now presented with this message every time I open any of my context definition files:

[image: sprign contexts]

And given these options:

[image: which option]

It doesn't seem to matter which option I select I am still presented with the message ... ? 
I have a *spring-servlet.xml* in WEB-INF which itself imports 3 different files (*hibernate.xml*, *security.xml*, and *beans.xml* which are stored in my resources directory and define beans related to their name).

Everything is working hunky-dory, just wanted to know what the message was supposed to signify?

Comment: I guess Intellij is smart enough to know that the beans defined in `beans.xml` will be included in the application context and servlet context (since it's a child of application context). As for XML Application Context, I don't really know what that is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but why is it telling me with a big error sign ?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. I don't know Intellij. Is there some error tab that you can look for more info/details? That red can be really annoying lol

Answer (score 7):

Had the same warning. Went to Project Settings -> Modules -> Spring and deleted all but one context which held all of my .xml files. No files should be deleted when you do this (it's just an IDEA config) and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and re-adding facets in project or module settings.